# Improving "Please Note: Names In Red Are Junior Staff"

Tags: labels

I'm replicating some old reports and making various improvements, including to general layout. One thing that grinds my gears a bit with them is long, wordy info labels above the body of the report that nobody notices or bothers reading.

One report has a table, with a column on it for the associated member of staff. If the staff member is a junior, their name should be displayed in red instead of black. Currently the original report looks like this (substitute names in `[brackets]` for red text):

```
Please Note: Names in red are junior staff
<<lots of space, report headings etc>>
|-------------------------------------------------|
| SomeDept                                        |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|Col1  | Col2  | Col3  | Col4  | Staff            |
|------|-------|-------|-------|------------------|
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Steve            |
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Mark, [John]     |
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Alice            |
```

I want to shorten that and stick it somewhere much more visible. I'm not sure where though. I thought the most logical place would be the column header:

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
| SomeDept                                        |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|Col1  | Col2  | Col3  | Col4  | Staff            |
|      |       |       |       | ([Junior staff]) |
|------|-------|-------|-------|------------------|
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Steve            |
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Mark, [John]     |
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Alice            |
```

But users may take that as a warning that the column *only* displays junior staff (the table is long and juniors will only feature in a handful of values that probably won't be visible from the top of the report, so they could easily assume all those displayed are juniors unless one happens to stand out as different to the others)

I can make it more explicit but it's starting to feel a little wordy for a column header.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| SomeDept                                               |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|Col1  | Col2  | Col3  | Col4  | Staff                   |
|      |       |       |       | ([Junior staff in red]) |
|------|-------|-------|-------|-------------------------|
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Steve                   |
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Mark, [John]            |
|blah  |blah   |blah   |blah   | Alice                   |
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of high school graduation programs where they use icons and a legend to indicate who got honor society, Dean's List, etc.

How about something like this? You can put the legend off to the side and "scroll lock" it if the table is really tall as you say.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7uBMt.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. I'm using Microsoft Report Server (by corporate mandate), so the scroll-locked key isn't an option, but the `*` should prompt people into looking. One issue with this (entirely specific to my use-case, not to detract from the answer) - the staff name entry on this system is free text and some names have been put in the system with weird characters in them (validation is rather lacking), so I think in my case people will just assume that `John*` was a typo haha

Comment: Oh bummer! there's no way to embed an icon, then, right? Or can you change the color or font style of just the `*`? I agree that just having it be inline (with the same font, etc.) makes it harder to see.